# Find a first pseudopalindrome in the array

Tags: c, binary-search, palindrome

I have a array of strings and I want to find the first pseudopalindrome in the array for every string (if there is any). So I decided to sort my array at first, then reverse the word and do a binary search for a reversed word. So here it is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char len(char *x){
char len = 0;

while (*x != '\0'){
    x++;
    len++;
}

return len;
}

char compare(char *x, char *y){
char x0 = &x;
char y0 = &y;
while (*x != '\0'){
    if (tolower(*x) < tolower(*y)) return -1;
    if (tolower(*x) > tolower(*y)) return 1;
    x++;
    y++;
}
// if we are here it means that strings are equal (case insensitive)
x = &x0;
y = &y0;
while (*x != '\0'){
    if (*x > *y) return -1;
    if (*x < *y) return 1;
    x++;
    y++;
}
// strings are equal (case sensitive)
return 0;
}


char *reverse(char *x){
int i, j;
char temp, *rev = NULL;

rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len(x)+1));
rev = strcpy(rev,x);
i = 0;
j = len(x) - 1;
while (i < j){
    temp = rev[i];
    rev[i] = x[j];
    rev[j] = temp;
    i++;
    j--;
}

return rev;
}

int binsearch(char *x, char *A, int len){
int l, r, m, index;

l = 0;
r = len - 1;
index = -1;
while (l <= r){
    m = (l + r) / 2;
    if (compare(x, A[m]) == 0){
        index = m;
        r = m - 1;
    }
    else if (compare(x, A[m]) == -1) r = m - 1;
    else l = m + 1;
}

return index;
}
int main()
{

int n, i, j, k, fnd;
char T[10000][101], temp[101];

scanf("%d", &n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%s", &T[i]);
}

for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    strcpy(temp, T[i]);
    j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && compare(T[j], temp) == 1){
        strcpy(T[j+1], T[j]);
        j--;
    }
    strcpy(T[j+1], temp);
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fnd = binsearch(reverse(T[i]), T, n);
    printf("%d", fnd);
}
return 0;
}
```

This program stops executing. The problem is probably with binary search as every function before executes well. But what's wrong with this binary search? Or what else can break the code?

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: A palindrome is a string that is a reverse of itself. Two different strings that are reverses of each other are not palindromes. Please get the terminology straight.

Comment: You don't need to write your `len` function.  C has a built-in function called `strlen` that does exactly what you wrote.

Comment: 1. Enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors. 2. Read the manual for strcpy. What header file does it require? 3. Read the synopsis of that heder file. Does it have functions you might want to use?

Comment: @n.m. I've added string.h. It still doesn't work.
Compiler warns me that function compare expect pointer instead of char. How should I pass a pointer to a function?

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  Did you read the warnings?

Comment: @ Yes, I did. And compiler doesn't return any warning regarding binsearch.

Comment: One error is enough to make the entire program invalid, which is exactly what happens here. You have to treat warnings as errors. That is, don't even try to run your program if there are any warnings. Especially if you don't understand and don't know how to fix them. Fixing the warnings is your first priority brcause *tey are errors*.

Comment: @n.m. How can I correct following errrors then? 
warning: passing argument 2 of 'compare' makes pointer from integer without a cast, warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char'

Comment: What is "pseudopalindrome"?

Comment: @EdHeal The word that is reverse of some string. (ex. example - elpmaxe)

Comment: Why have you changed it from palindrome to pseudopalindrome in the title? These are two different problems.

Comment: @EdHeal I've changed it after n.m.'s comment.

Comment: Just sort the letters of the two words into order. Then compare.

Comment: You should write a question that specifically asks about the errors/warnings you are getting. Don't use comments for that. By the way there are [more errors than you cite](https://ideone.com/VyKiaB).

Answer (score 0):

Does the return type causing the problem .. for binary search no return type is mentioned

Edit 1. But you have not mentioned return type for function in its declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char len(char *x){
char len = 0;

while (*x != '\0'){
    x++;
    len++;
}

return len;
}

char compare(char *x, char *y){
char* x0 = x;
char* y0 = y;
while (*x != '\0'){
    int a0 = tolower(*x);
    int b0 = tolower(*y);
    if ( a0 < b0) 
    return -1;
    if ( a0 > b0) 
    return 1;
    x++;
    y++;
}
// if we are here it means that strings are equal (case insensitive)
x = x0;
y = y0;
while (*x != '\0'){
    if (*x > *y) return -1;
    if (*x < *y) return 1;
    x++;
    y++;
}
// strings are equal (case sensitive)
return 0;
}


char *reverse(char *x){
int i, j;
char temp, *rev = NULL;

rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*(len(x)+1));
rev = strcpy(rev,x);
i = 0;
j = len(x) - 1;
while (i < j){
    temp = rev[i];
    rev[i] = x[j];
    rev[j] = temp;
    i++;
    j--;
}

return rev;
}

int binarysearch(char *x,char A[][101], int len){
int l, r, m, index;

l = 0;
r = len - 1;
index = -1;
while (l <= r){
    m = (l + r) / 2;
    if (compare(x, A[m]) == 0){
        index = m;
        r = m - 1;
    }
    else if (compare(x, A[m]) == -1) r = m - 1;
    else l = m + 1;
}

return index;
}
int main()
{

int n, i, j, k, fnd;
char T[10000][101], temp[101];

scanf("%d", &n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%s", &T[i]);
}

for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
    strcpy(temp, T[i]);
    j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && compare(T[j], temp) == 1){
        strcpy(T[j+1], T[j]);
        j--;
    }
    strcpy(T[j+1], temp);
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fnd = binarysearch(reverse(T[i]), T, n);
    printf("%d", fnd);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I return an index from binary search

Comment: I declared it as `int binsearch` (edited). Some mistake while copying.

Comment: It doesn't compile - error in binsearch declaration: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token.

Comment: updated only one warning is there .. give try to resolve it

Comment: I've got no warnings. However, the program doesn't catch the reverse of the word when some letter is different case (ex. example elpmaXe). I've tried to solve it by using tolower function in binary search but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but code in comments is painful to read.

You may also try to simplify your code; it's quite astonishing to have some much code for just a palindrome; some functions you are reimplementing are part of standard c (strlen, strcasecmp, strdup)
The function for telling if a word is palindrome is expected to really simple; here a sample of what it could be

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isspeudopalindrom(const char *x){
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x) / 2; ++i) {
        if (tolower(x[i]) != tolower(x[strlen(x) - 1 - i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if (isspeudopalindrom(argv[i]))
            printf("palindrom\n");
        else
            printf("not palindrom\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```